# Update Json field via Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a json like this coming from an input port:

```
{
"url": "blablabla",
"keyword": "foo"
}
```

then I have to generate a new json to pass to a post call. The new json is something like this:

```
  {
     "requests": [
        {
            "source": "blablabla",
            "params": {
                "keywords": [
                    "something"
                ],
                "sub-field1": true
           }
        }
    ],
    "field1": "1",
    "field2": "2",
    "field3": false
}
```

where the array keywords should be replaced with a new array with the value of the previous Json ("foo"). The resulting is:

```
   {
     "requests": [
        {
            "source": "blablabla",
            "params": {
                "keywords": [
                    "foo"
                ],
                "sub-field1": true
           }
        }
    ],
    "field1": "1",
    "field2": "2",
    "field3": false
}
```

then i have to call a function via REST API Post.

The problem is that I don't know how to perform the replace of the field value

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html

Comment: Hi Sdaris, thanks for the response...it is not clear to me how to use it..I first have to generateflowfile with the final json and then use the updaterecord? could you please provide and example?

Comment: Is your input data always a single piece of Json? I.e. you only ever have 1 input JSON object per FlowFile? If so, it's probably easier to do EvaluateJsonPath (put URL and KEYWORD in to attributes)-> ReplaceText (replace Entire Text with a template Request JSON) -> UpdateRecord (with JSON reader & writer set to Infer, manipulate the JSON as needed) -> InvokeHTTP. You could skip the UpdateRecord and just use Expression Language inside ReplaceText, but UpdateRecord will give you more options to manipulate easily.

Comment: I don't know if i correctly understood your question....basically, My input json for the post is always the same (the one that I put in the first post) but with different "keywords"

Comment: furthermore, how can I put the json in the replace text block?

Comment: last thing, what does it mean (with JSON reader & writer set to Infer, manipulate the JSON as needed)  ?

Comment: You can paste the text in the Replacement Value box https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/

Comment: Record reader & writers take Schemas to understand the data - you can use Infer to let NiFi work the Schema out itself, rather than setting it https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.json.JsonRecordSetWriter/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try JoltTransformJSON with the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "url": "requests[0].source",
      "keyword": "requests[0].params.keywords[]",
      "#1": "requests[0].params.sub-field1"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "field1": "1",
      "field2": "2",
      "field3": false
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: hi @mattyb, this seems to be good but the desired output is not what I expect (I made a mistake in the example, sub-field1 is a boolean....). "sub-field1" has true (bool) as value so I don't know how to manage it. How can I manage it? –